# pytest, raise_for_status with Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>

Tags: python, http, python-requests, pytest

This is for documething something I stumbled upon for a long time.

This is not working. The `try/except/else` clause will swallow the exception generated by `r.raise_for_status()`.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
import pytest
import logging

def fetch(url):
    """HTTP request"""
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as err:
        logging.warning(f'Fetching url failed {err}')
    else:
        print(r.data)


def test_fetch(mocker):
    """Test."""
    mock_response = mocker.Mock(requests.Response)
    expected_exc = HTTPError()
    mock_response.raise_for_status.side_effect = expected_exc
    mocker.patch.object(requests, 'get')
    requests.get.return_value = mock_response
    r = fetch('http://httpbin.org/status/400')
    with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as err_msg:
        r.raise_for_status()
```

The error message received from pytest is

```
example.py F                                                                                                                      [100%]

====================================================================== FAILURES =======================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________ test_fetch ______________________________________________________________________

mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockFixture object at 0x1095cd100>

    def test_fetch(mocker):
        """Test."""
        mock_response = mocker.Mock(requests.Response)
        expected_exc = HTTPError()
        mock_response.raise_for_status.side_effect = expected_exc
        mocker.patch.object(requests, 'get')
        requests.get.return_value = mock_response
        with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as err_msg:
>           fetch('http://httpbin.org/status/400')
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>

example.py:25: Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured log call ------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING  root:example.py:12 Fetching url failed
=============================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================
FAILED example.py::test_fetch - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>
================================================================== 1 failed in 0.20s ==================================================================
```

I gave the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you really feel, that you need to test the raise_for_status here. It is necessary to raise again the exception.

```py
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
import pytest
import logging

def fetch(url):
    """HTTP request"""
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as err:
        logging.warning(f'Fetching url failed {err}')
        # HERE raise again.
        raise
    else:
        print(r.data)


def test_fetch(mocker):
    """Test."""
    mock_response = mocker.Mock(requests.Response)
    expected_exc = HTTPError()
    mock_response.raise_for_status.side_effect = expected_exc
    mocker.patch.object(requests, 'get')
    requests.get.return_value = mock_response
    with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as err_msg:
        fetch('http://httpbin.org/status/400')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just doing the logging in except block
Also, raise.

```
except HTTPError as err:
    logging.warning(f'Fetching url failed {err}')
    raise
```

Because: pytest.raises looks for raise Conditions rather than exceptions.